# getimagesize size, wordpress site

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Can you please help me with this issue.
I bought plugin from codecanyon, but author doesn't care about customers problems
and I don't how to fix it.

It's wordpress based website.
http://www.anetastrzalka.com/media/

Thumbnails are not showing up and that's the error:
Warning: getimagesize() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/kps/public_html/anetastrzalka.com/wp-content/plugins/ajax-portfolio/php/class-image-resize.php on line 75

Thank you in advance
and have a great weekend

Chris

Comment: show the code on line 75

Comment: Here is it, thanks: $new_img_size = getimagesize( $new_img_path );

Comment: Can you show how you assigned a value to `$new_img_path`?

Comment: I did nothing, I just installed this plugin to my wordpress and was trying to use it

Comment: You are likely getting a `WP_Error` object. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_resize. You need to change your plugin to use https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor instead.

Comment: Are you sure the image really exists? Generally we get such fatal error when the given image path has not any actual image